# How to restore lock screen option in settings?

Tags: security, lock-screen

My lock screen option from settings is gone, and neither `Windows+L` nor `Ctrl+Alt+L` are locking the screen - they are simply turning it off. When I move the mouse, no password is prompted for before resuming operation.

How can I restore the missing locking functionality?

Using Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

Comment: [link](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/36256/how-do-i-disable-the-gnome-lock-screen/)

Comment: This is the same solution as the duplicate candidate.

Comment: That's right, I hadn't seen that.

Comment: No worries you were probably writing the answer at the same time I was voting to close as duplicate question.

Comment: That works to restore the "locl" option on the menu.  ALT+F2 and then "r" to reload gnome.  Won't log you out.